# Get dimensions with python selenium

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping

I'm tying to get dimensions from a website. The table present on the page is in this format and details as color, dimensions, material and so on, are not all the time in the same order[as it can be noticed in the image examples below].

[image]
[image]

I am interested to extract this 'Peso articolo' value which can be also found as 'Peso do produto' or 'Peso del producto'. The issue is that Xpath for this is different from a page to another and the class is the same for all the details from the table.

[image]

I'm using this code to extract but since the position is different on each page, sometimes extracts material for example instead of dimension[using Xpath].

```
def get_dimensions(driver):
# details XPATH
# details_xpath = '//*[@id="productDetails_techSpec_section_1"]/tbody/tr[4]/td'
details_xpath = '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[8]/div[7]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td'
found = False
retries = 1
dimensions = ''
while retries > 0 and not found:
    try:
        retries = retries - 1
        dimensions_elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, details_xpath))
        )
        found = True
        dimensions = dimensions_elem.text
    except:
        pass
        print('dimensions not found! Retrying...')

return dimensions
```

Is there a way I could update this to access only those th classes where the value is 'Peso articolo' or 'Peso do produto' or 'Peso del producto' and get the value from the td class?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `td` tag wrt to `th` tag value `Peso articolo` Use any of the following `xpath` to get the element.

```
details_xpath ="//th[normalize-space(text())='Peso articolo']/following::td[1]"
```

or

```
details_xpath ="//tr[./th[normalize-space(text())='Peso articolo']]/td"
```

Comment: thank you but its not returning any value now.

Comment: @isa : instead of `presence_of_element_located` change to `visibility_of_element_located`

Comment: just did but nothing changed. I have tried with both options.

Comment: @isa: can you share the url? it seems xpath is correct however element is not visible on the page. Share the url to have a look.

Comment: https://www.amazon.it/dp/B09D9BZRZT

Comment: @isa : there was space in the element text value. I have updated the `xpath`. try now.

Comment: thank you so much, it is working now, I will mark as the correct answer. One king request, do I need to create a kind of loop to have a condition for all three options: Peso articolo , Peso do produto and Peso del producto? This may differ according to the detail page that its getting accessed

Comment: @Isa : loop won't help here since you have different header text against value. you need to take that individually. Appreciate if you upvote the answer that will help future readers.

Comment: @Isa : you could try this `xpath` which will cover all three text if you like `//th[contains(.,'Peso')]/following::td[1]`

Comment: thank you so much, its working. I really appreciate putting extra effort in this even after I marked the response as the correct one, many thanks!